# How keep the order of categorical x on a histogram ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I want to plot a histogram with categories on x and scores on y.
The order from the table should be kept in the plot, but right now the plot gets reordered and the several posts on this I found on SO have not helped my case. for instance I tried this: [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

table <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), b = c("grease", "surf", 
"lift", "zen", "ufo", "nothing"), c = c("3976.65457028497", "3700.27298336394", 
"3691.44157683915", "3687.89781035758", "3685.83200999925", "3685.44486138222"
)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

ggplot(data=table) + geom_histogram(aes(x=b,y=c),stat='identity')
```

So this orders them in alphabetical order while I want them in decreasing c order. How would I do this?

Comment: Seriously what is with the downvotes? Did I piss someone off or is there something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood, this is what you are trying to do (I renamed your object table to table.dt):

```
ggplot(data=table.dt,aes(x=reorder(b,-as.numeric(c)),y=c)) +
  geom_histogram(stat='identity')
```

Comment: BTW, you can't mask a function with a non-function variable in R. (It is a [lisp-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace).)

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that `table$c` is stored as a character ... which may not be intended